# How do I access my hard drive? (not running dual boot)

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I installed ubuntu on my former windows C drive, it does not have windows on it anymore. However, once I installed Ubuntu, I cannot access my hard drive storage (which used to be D on windows)

I get this error,

[image]

I think this is because the hard drive is in NTFS? If so, is it possible to convert it in a way so Ubuntu can read and write?

Comment: Was Windows version 8 or later with always on hibernation? You would then need to boot Windows and turn off the always on hibernation or fast start up setting to clean hibernation settings on data partition. http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation You may be able to remove hiberfile to allow use as NTFS. If no data to save then just reformat to ext4.

Comment: **unclean** [...] windows cache, refused to mount [...] **unsafe state**

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu.

Use `gparted` to open a very useful interface that will allow you to format the drive in any way you want (create new partitions, merge or move existing ones, etc.).  When you go through the options, format it to EXT4 (latest linux standard) and make sure you tick the option to mount it when starting up the computer.  You will have to give it a specific mount point, say `/media` or `/backup`.  This you will access through the file manager using that folder name.  Note, however, that this will create a **separate** disc partition.

Instead, if you are new to linux, what I would suggest is that you grow the current disc partition to include that space.  If you already created partitions when you started (typically `swap`, `/` and `/home` will be the fundamental partitions) I suggest you append the extra space to `/home`.

Warning: the procedure of either creating a new partition or appending the space to an existing partition will delete ALL the files currently in that partition.  This process is irreversible.

GParted should be installed by default.  [Here is some additional information about GParted.](http://gparted.org/)